# Class methods in main loop?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios6, viewcontroller, iphone-developer-program

I have some class methods from the ViewController class that are activated with BOOL Types.  I want to insert those methods into the main loop so when they BOOL's are activated the method will run, but for some reason i can't get the viewController methods in to main.

But I'm getting an error for the method call and the method isn't showing up in auto complete.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

#import "AppDelegate.h"

#import "ViewController.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool
    {

        [ViewController singleBoxShow];

        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
    }
}
```

Comment: What does "activated with BOOL Types" mean? That doesn't make very much sense.

Comment: "Activated with BOOL types" sounds like the label on some kind of health product.

Comment: Sorry guys, but basically this.

Comment: BOOL open;

-(void)activator
{
    if(open == YES)
    {
        //code here
    }
}

Answer (score 3):

This is the wrong place for that.  The view hierarchy isn't even close to existing yet there. Don't mess with `main()` without a *very* good reason.

Instead this should go in the callbacks of the `ApplicationDelegate`.  Such as `applicationDidFinishLaunchWithOptions:`.

Comment: so alex if you can kind of explain how I go about using the delegate? Is it a loop that will always make an pick up the calls.  I'm just use to the main going through it s motions you know?